# SailsJS won't load database configuration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

This is my `config/adapters.js` file:

```
module.exports.adapters = {
  mongo: {
    module: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'testing1234',
    database: 'sailstest'
  }
};
```

This is the model's configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  adapter: 'mongo',
  attributes: {
    username: 'STRING',
    password: 'STRING',
    firstName: 'STRING',
    lastName: 'STRING'
  }

};
```

When I try to run `sails lift` I get the following error:

```
/Users/mike/Dropbox/mongodb/sails-test/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:216
  if(typeof databaseName !== 'string') throw new Error("database name must be 

      ^
Error: database name must be a string
    at validateDatabaseName (/Users/mike/Dropbox/mongodb/sails-test/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:216:46)
    at new Db (/Users/mike/Dropbox/mongodb/sails-test/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:96:3)
    at createConnection (/Users/mike/Dropbox/mongodb/sails-test/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:497:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an authentication error that was not being reported properly.